# Does Comanche have romantic feelings for Shades?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, luke-cage

In either episode 6 or 7 of *Luke Cage*, Shades and Comanche sit in the barber shop and talk about old times and Shades keeps repeating "inside was inside."

Reading into the scene, it seems that they may have had a physical relationship in prison.  So, does Comanche have romantic feelings for Shades?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The consensus is [Yes](https://io9.gizmodo.com/luke-cages-complicated-queer-romance-is-a-part-of-gangs-1827213580), but it's not particularly hard to miss!

There are repeated references to a prior sexual relationship, which Shades dismisses as intended as companionship to 'stay sane', but Comanche insists was something more meaningful.

Comment: Also near the end, doesn't Mariah mock Shades specifically about that?

Comment: What's maybe slightly easier to miss is that, despite his repeated denials, Shades has romantic feelings for Comanche, which he doesn't want to admit. That's why he said he loved Comanche so much he couldn't see that the latter was an informant, and arguably why he reacted so violently to Comanche's "betrayal," and *definitely* a big part of why he turned on Mariah (whom he also cared for); I think that for Shades, if not for Mariah, he and Comanche would have "gotten out" already and Comanche's death wouldn't have happened.